# Firebase data to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a React component that I'm trying to pass some props but I get an **Uncaught Error: App.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.** when I try to return it inside the snapshot.

```
// cache settings data
fire.settings = {};
fire.settings.ref = fire.database.ref('settings');

// main app build
class App extends Component {
    render() {
      // get values from firebase
      fire.settings.ref.on('value', function(data) {
        return (<Home settings={data.val()} />);
      });
    }
}
```

So I started messing around with generators and I get the component to render, but I just get an empty object in my settings prop.

```
// main app build
class App extends Component {
    render() {
      // get values from firebase
      function* generator() {
        fire.settings.ref.on('value', function(data) {
          fire.settings.snapshot = data.val();
        });
        yield fire.settings.snapshot;
      }
      // init generator and return homepage
      let promise = generator();
      return (<Home settings={promise.next()} />);
    }
}
```

As well as using componentDidMount()

```
// main app build
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fire.settings.ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            this.props.settings = snapshot.val();
        }, (error) => console.log(error), this);
    }
    render() {
        return (<Home settings={this.props.settings}/>);
    }
}
```

**SOLVED**

Pass the value through the render to the component

```
// init render
fire.settings.ref.on('value', function(data) {
  ReactDOM.render(
      <App settings={data.val()}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
});
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to return your element inside callback of a listener which is asynchronous. Instead of that you should set listener inside `componentDidMount` and call `setState` inside the callback.

```
// cache settings data
fire.settings = {};
fire.settings.ref = fire.database.ref('settings');

// main app build
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: null };
    this.onSettingsChanged = this.onSettingsChanged.bind(this);
  }

  onSettingsChanged(data){
    this.setState({data: data.val()});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fire.settings.ref.on('value', this.onSettingsChanged);
  }

  render() {
    return (<Home settings={this.state.data}/>);
  }
}
```

Comment: I get a couple errors - 
1. Warning: getInitialState was defined on App, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Comment: `getInitialState()` is for ES5 (using `React.createClass()`). For ES6 classes, you just set the state in the constructor. `constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = { data: null }; }` Furthermore, for ES6+, you can just set state using a property initializer as such, inside the class: `state = { data: null }`

Comment: Oops! I have messed up with ES5 and ES6 syntax. Fixed it and updated the answer!